# How to change char in jni from java

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk

I have this code as example in my jni : `char m= 0` 
now how can i give an command from java to change the char in jni from 0 to 1 as example?

Comment: So export a function that does `m = 1;`. This sounds like one of the most trivial examples of JNI, so it's unclear to me what the problem is. Android Studio's project wizard even includes a Native C++ template that creates one exported function for you if you don't know the syntax.

Comment: the problem is  if i have an integer in c++ how can i change th value of this integer by java